# Facebook app crashes on Android Genymotion Emulator?

Tags: android, facebook, genymotion

The Facebook app (and Messenger) app crashes on Android Genymotion Emulator on OS X v10.10.3. Other apps that I have installed till now, run flawlessly without any error. Here is the logcat generated when the app starts (& crashes),

```
03-14 21:20:25.351      516-721/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 pkg=com.facebook.katana cmp=com.facebook.katana/.LoginActivity} from pid 1752
03-14 21:20:25.591      516-674/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Start proc com.facebook.katana:nodex for activity com.facebook.katana/.LoginActivity: pid=3031 uid=10078 gids={50078, 1028, 1015, 3003}
03-14 21:20:25.647    3031-3031/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'com.facebook.katana.app.WallpaperFacebookApplicationImpl', referenced from method com.facebook.katana.app.FacebookApplication.a
03-14 21:20:25.659    3031-3031/? D/CatchMeIfYouCan﹕ Process (nodex) ca: '/data/data/com.facebook.katana/app_cmiyc/902B45094161489D3AB6470A02B22D0D4A228C3001'
03-14 21:20:25.659    3031-3031/? D/CatchMeIfYouCan﹕ Process (nodex) fc: '/data/data/com.facebook.katana/app_cmiyc/902B45094161489D3AB6470A02B22D0D4A228C3002'
03-14 21:20:25.659    3031-3031/? D/ACRA﹕ ACRA is enabled for com.facebook.katana, intializing...
03-14 21:20:25.663    3031-3031/? D/ACRA﹕ Looking for error files in /data/data/com.facebook.katana/app_acra-reports
03-14 21:20:25.663    3031-3031/? D/ACRA﹕ Looking for error files in /data/data/com.facebook.katana/app_minidumps
03-14 21:20:25.667    3031-3031/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.facebook.katana-2/libgnustl_shared.so 0xa50c1508
03-14 21:20:25.807      144-144/? I/DEBUG﹕ pid: 3031, tid: 3031, name: ok.katana:nodex  >>> com.facebook.katana:nodex <<<
03-14 21:20:26.075     516-3049/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ Force finishing activity com.facebook.katana/.LoginActivity
03-14 21:20:26.611      516-726/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Process com.facebook.katana:nodex (pid 3031) has died.
```

The specific error is,

```
21:20:25.647    3031-3031/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'com.facebook.katana.app.WallpaperFacebookApplicationImpl', referenced from method com.facebook.katana.app.FacebookApplication.a
```

Has anybody fixed the problem?

Comment: which genymotion version? which android version?

Comment: v2.4.0. I updated the VM to Android 5.x.x & now works fine with the Google Play Service.

Answer (score 0):

As far right now, I am using the Google 4.3 in the Virtual Machine, and Facebook app (& messenger) work fine. I will wait the bug to be fixed.